# got Type 'void' is not assignable to type '() => void' in react typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I tried to pass the props like

```
<Mycomp
 deleteAcc={handleDelete(accountId)}
/>
```

to another component. I write the props like

```
interface AccProps {
 deleteAcc: () => void;
}
```

and call the function like

```
deleteAcc()
```

But I got the below error

```
Type 'void' is not assignable to type '() => void'
```

Not sure what I have missed here.

Comment: pass it like this:
`deleteAcc={() => handleDelete(accountId)}`

Comment: Make sure you read the react docs, specially this https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html

Answer (score 8):

When you pass `handleDelete(accountId)` as a prop, the function is called immediately and its return value (in this case, a `void`) is the one being passed as a prop.
If the function must take this particular argument, send it as a callback:

```js
<Mycomp deleteAcc={() => handleDelete(accountId)} />
```

Since `handleDelete(accountId)` reutrn `void`, this callback is typed `() => void` and therefore suits the prop type.

If the function does not have to accept an argument, you can send it by name:

```js
<Mycomp deleteAcc={handleDelete} />
```

Often a good idea is to create a unique wrapper function in the component and send it by name, for example:

```js
const wrapper = () => {
  handleDelete(accountId);
};

<Mycomp deleteAcc={wrapper} />
```

Answer (score 3):

Most likely because the return value type of the `handleDelete` function is `void`, and you pass the return value of `handleDelete`. while `deleteAcc` requires a function with `() => void` type.

Try:

```
<Mycomp deleteAcc={() => handleDelete(accountId)}/>
```